# Vue.js computed property loses its reactivity when passed through an event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I have a `Modal` component in my main app that gets passed content via an event whenever a modal has to be shown. Modal content is always a list with an action associated with each item, like "select" or "remove":

```
Vue.component('modal', {
  data() {
    return {
      shown: false,
      items: [],
      callback: ()=>{}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('showModal', this.show);
  },
  template: `<ul v-if="shown">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }} <button @click="callback(item)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>`,
  methods: {
    show(items, callback) {
      this.shown = true;
      this.items = items;
      this.callback = callback;
    }
  }
});
```

Sadly, when passing a computed property to that modal like in the component below, the reactive link gets broken -> if the action is "remove", the list is not updated.

```
Vue.component('comp', {
  data() {
    return {obj: {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'}}
  },
  computed: {
    objKeys() {
      return Object.keys(this.obj);
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
    <modal></modal>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    remove(name) {
      this.$delete(this.obj, name);
    },
    showModal() {
      EventBus.$emit('showModal', this.objKeys, this.remove);
    }
  }
});
```

See the minimal use case in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/christophfriedrich/cm778wgj/14/

I think this is a bug - shouldn't Vue remember that `objKeys` is used for rendering in `Modal` and update it? (The forwarding of the change of `obj` to `objKeys` works.) If not, what am I getting wrong and how could I achieve my desired result?

Comment: You are removing object properties, vue doesn't watch that... you should add a watcher instead

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Indeed a watcher is needed.

Comment: A watcher or a shared state between both components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch

Comment: @samayo Vue DOES watch that when I use the $delete function - at least that's how I understand https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete Did you look at my fiddle? The rendering in `comp`'s template updates perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the modal working with its own copy of `items`:

```
 template: `<ul v-if="shown">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }} <button @click="callback(item)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>`,
  methods: {
    show(items, callback) {
      this.shown = true;
      this.items = items;
      this.callback = callback;
    }
  }
```

That copy is made once, upon the call to `show`, and what you are copying is just the value of the computed at the time you emit the `showModal` event. What `show` receives is not a computed, and what it assigns is not a computed. It's just a value.

If, anywhere in your code, you made an assignment like

```
someDataItem = someComputed;
```

the data item would not be a functional copy of the computed, it would be a snapshot of its value at the time of the assignment. This is why copying values around in Vue is a bad practice: they don't automatically stay in sync.

Instead of copying values around, you can pass a function that returns the value of interest; effectively a get function. For syntactic clarity, you can make a computed based on that function. Then your code becomes

```js
const EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('comp', {
  data() {
    return {
      obj: {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    objKeys() {
      return Object.keys(this.obj);
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>Entire object: {{ obj }}</div>
    <div>Just the keys: {{ objKeys }}</div>
    <button @click="remove('a')">Remove a</button>
    <button @click="remove('b')">Remove b</button>
    <button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
    <modal></modal>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    remove(name) {
      this.$delete(this.obj, name);
    },
    showModal() {
      EventBus.$emit('showModal', () => this.objKeys, this.remove);
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('modal', {
  data() {
    return {
      shown: false,
      getItems: null,
      callback: () => {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('showModal', this.show);
  },
  template: `<div v-if="shown">
  <ul v-if="items.length>0">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }} <button @click="callback(item)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <em v-else>empty</em>
</div>`,
  computed: {
    items() {
      return this.getItems && this.getItems();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show(getItems, callback) {
      this.shown = true;
      this.getItems = getItems;
      this.callback = callback;
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp></comp>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a value to a function, you are not passing a prop to a component. Props are reactive, but values are just values. You include `modal` in the template of `comp`, so rework it to take (at least) `items` as a prop. Then it will be reactive.

I would recommend having the remove process follow the emit-event-and-process-in-parent rather than passing a callback.

```js
const EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('comp', {
  data() {
    return {
      obj: {
        a: 'foo',
        b: 'bar'
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    objKeys() {
      return Object.keys(this.obj);
    }
  },
  template: `<div>
    <div>Entire object: {{ obj }}</div>
    <div>Just the keys: {{ objKeys }}</div>
    <button @click="remove('a')">Remove a</button>
    <button @click="remove('b')">Remove b</button>
    <button @click="showModal">Show Modal</button>
    <modal :items="objKeys" event-name="remove" @remove="remove"></modal>
  </div>`,
  methods: {
    remove(name) {
      this.$delete(this.obj, name);
    },
    showModal() {
      EventBus.$emit('showModal');
    }
  }
});

Vue.component('modal', {
  props: ['items', 'eventName'],
  data() {
    return {
      shown: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    EventBus.$on('showModal', this.show);
  },
  template: `<div v-if="shown">
  <ul v-if="items.length>0">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      {{ item }} <button @click="emitEvent(item)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <em v-else>empty</em>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    show(items, callback) {
      this.shown = true;
    },
    emitEvent(item) {
      this.$emit(this.eventName, item);
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp></comp>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to be able to trigger the modal from any point in the code, so passing `items` as a prop doesn't really fix my problem.
Also, when I pass `obj` directly (instead of the `objKeys` property computed off it), everything works as I expect it, see [this slightly changed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christophfriedrich/jL1z0vxw/3/). And that although I technically still just pass a value to a function.

Comment: Well, sure, an object that contains reactive elements still contains reactive elements. But an object is passed by reference, not by value. (Technically, it's passed by value, but the value *is* a reference.)

Comment: My confusion remains because I'd think a computed and a normal property should behave equally. However, your other answer indeed solves this question nicely for my purpose, so I marked this question as solved and asked [a new one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49283457/3746543) for this other aspect, encouraged by your (meanwhile deleted?) other comment to do so.